# configure mime types windows azure websites php app

Tags: php, css, azure, webfonts, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Windows Azure Websites to host a php app. My app uses webfonts (css3 feature) and I need to configure extensions such as .eot; .woff to avoid 404 errors. I know that it's possible to set this kind of configs using web.config in a .net app, but for a php site, what can I do? Unfortunately there's no RDP for websites. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I could solve this just adding a web.config to root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: After much confusion on the mime type for woff, the official [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b) states it should be "application/font-woff" without the "x-".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here, I also hade the problem with woff2 files and got rid of the errors by adding this web.config file to the root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

By using the kudu service to add the file to the wwwroot directory as described here:
http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/