# ASP.NET Video webm not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webm

I have created a basic website in asp.net. I'm playing with the azure platform, but I'm having some difficulties. 
The website contains a video (.webm)

```
<video autoplay loop muted class="background_login" src="Content/background.webm"></video>
```

The video does load when running locally, but when I have pushed it to the azurewebsites.net it stays black. 
I have read about the mime types, and that they should be declared. So I put this in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
</staticContent>
```

It still doesn't work, though. The website can be found at: 'link deleted' 
The video is stored in the Content folder (checked if it's actually there with FileZilla, and it's there): 'link deleted' 
Calling it directly gives a internal server error.
Any ideas of what might go wrong here?

Comment: Try this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663535/configure-mime-types-windows-azure-websites-php-app

Comment: I have seen that answer too, but adding the <remove> tag does not help.

Comment: Can you put the same type of config inside `Content` folder, see if that helps!

Comment: This doesn't work either, I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes if you have ASP.NET Forms authentication enabled you get HTTP 500 errors requesting static content files (.mp3, .mp4 ...)

Removing the mimeMap element should fix the problem.

Change your staticContent section to :

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Removing it gives me another error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: I have added a webconfig with your method in the content map, and removed the staticContent from the main webconfig, and it seems to work now. thanks